# How to fix a memory leak in class components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass a value in another componet with `sessionStorage`.
After I did that, it showed me an error:  `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.` and `TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function`

AddLanguage.js

```
import React from "react";

export default class AddLanguage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      message: "",
      items: [],
      hasError: ""
    };
  }

  updateMessage(event) {
    this.setState({
      message: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    var items = this.state.items;

    items.push(this.state.message);

    this.setState({
      items: items,
      message: ""
    });
  }

  handleItemChanged(i, event) {
    const items = event.target.value;
    console.log("items", items);

    this.setState((prev) => {
      const currList = prev.items;
      console.log("currList", currList);

      const isDuplicate = currList.some(
        (lang, idx) => idx !== i && lang) === items
      );

      sessionStorage.setItem('statement', JSON.stringify(isDuplicated)) // this I want to get in the other component


      if (isDupliacte) {
        return { ...prev, hasError: "A BIG ERROR" };
      } else {
        currList[i] = items;
        return { ...prev, items: currList };
      }
    });

    sessionStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify({ items, message: "" }));

  }

  handleItemDeleted(i) {
    var items = this.state.items;

    items.splice(i, 1);

    this.setState({
      items: items
    });
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.userItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("items"));
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("items")) {
      this.setState({
        items: this.userItems.items,
        message: this.userItems.message,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        items: [],
        message: "",
      });
    }
  }

  renderRows() {
    var context = this;

    return this.state.items.map(function (o, i) {
      return (
        <tr key={"item-" + i}>
          <td>
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={o}
                autoComplete="off"
                onChange={context.handleItemChanged.bind(context, i)}
              />
            </div>

            {this.state.hasError && (
              <div>
                <label></label>
                <div>
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    className="inline-block mr-2 h-5 w-5"
                    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    fill="currentColor"
                  >
                  </svg>{" "}
                  {this.state.hasError}
                  {""}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </td>
          <td >
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={context.handleItemDeleted.bind(context, i)}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    }, this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <table>
            <thead">
              <tr>
                <th
                >
                  Button
                </th>
                <th
                >
                  Info
                </th>
                <th
                >
                  ACTION
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.renderRows()}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            className="btn-main"
            disabled={this.state.items.length >= 2}
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          >
            <PlusSmIcon />
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have made search for this error, and most of the solution were in `useEffect()`, but the actually code is in a class component.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your `handleItemChanged` function, some typos, bad variable name that let you make other mistakes, i tried to fix that:

```
  handleItemChanged(i, event) {
    // This contain a single item so use proper variable name
    const item = event.target.value;

    this.setState((prev) => {
      // Make a copy of current state, just for being safe
      const currList = prev.items.slice();

      // You had an extra parentesis in here
      const isDuplicate = currList.some(
        (lang, idx) => idx !== i && lang === item
      );

      // And a typo in here
      sessionStorage.setItem('statement', JSON.stringify(isDuplicate)); // this I want to get in the other component

      // Here you can set the state, you weren't removing the error when you delete or type another character
      currList[i] = item;
      return {
        ...prev,
        items: currList,
        hasError: isDuplicate ? 'A BIG ERROR' : '',
      };
    });

    // And here you were setting the `items` wrong and this was giving you the error
    sessionStorage.setItem(
      'items',
      JSON.stringify({ items: this.state.items, message: '' })
    );
  }
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k1zqrl?file=src%2FAddLanguage.js